# Back to basics for the XOR problem - fundamentaly confused

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, perceptron, mlp

This is something that has been bothering me for a while about XOR and MLP; it may be basic (if so, apoligies in advance), but I would like to know.

There are many approaches to solving XOR with MLP, but generally they look like this:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

X = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
y = [0, 1, 1, 0]

model = MLPClassifier(
    activation='relu', max_iter=1000, hidden_layer_sizes=(4,2))
```

Now to fit the model:

```
model.fit(X, y)
```

And, guess what?

```
print('score:', model.score(X, y))
```

outputs a perfect

> score: 1.0

But what is being predicted and scored? In the case of XOR we have a dataset which, by definition(!) has four rows, two features and one binary label. There is no standard `X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test` to work with. By definition, again, there is no unseen data for the model to digest.

The prediction takes place in the form of

```
model.predict(X)
```

which is exactly the same `X` that training was performed on.

So doesn't the model just spit back the `y` it was trained on? How do we know the model "learned" anything?

EDIT: Just to try to clarify what baffles me - the features have 2 and only 2 unique values; the 2 unique values have 4 and only 4 possible combinations. The right label for each possible combination is already present in the label column. So what is there for the model to "learn" when `fit()` is called? And how is this "learning" performed? How can the model ever be "wrong" when it has access to the "right" answer for each possible combination of inputs?

Again, sorry for what is probably a very basic question.

Comment: Asking this kind of conceptual question about ML is probably a better fit for [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Arne - You're probably right. I'm just conditioned to use SO... Next I'll try that or one of the other SE boards for this type of questions.

Comment: No worries, it seems you did get a good answer after all. I mainly wanted to make sure that you are aware about the existence of a stackexchange dedicated to statistics and models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing is that XOR problem was proposed to demonstrate how some models can learn non-linear problems and some models can't.

So when a model gets 1.0 accuracy on the dataset you mentioned, it's notable since it has learned a non-linear problem. The fact that it has learned the training data is enough for us to know that it can [potentially] learn non-linear models. Notice that if this wasn't the case your model would get a very low accuracy like 0.25 since it divides the 2D space into two sub-spaces by a line.

To understand this better, let's see a case where a model can't learn the data under this same circumstances:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=100)
_, acc = model.evaluate(X, y)
print('acc = ' + str(acc))
```

which gives:

> acc = 0.5

As you can see this model can't classify the data it has already seen. The reason is, this is a non-linear data and our model can only classify linear data.([here](https://medium.com/@jayeshbahire/the-xor-problem-in-neural-networks-50006411840b) is a link to understand the non-linearity of XOR problem better). As soon as we add another layer to our network it will be able to solve this problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu'))


tb_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./test/', write_graph=True)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=5, callbacks=[tb_callback, ])
acc = model.evaluate(X, y)
print('acc = ' + str(acc))
```

which gives:

> acc = 1.0

By adding only one neuron our model learned to do what it couldn't learn in 100 epochs with 1 layer (even though it had already seen the data).

So to sum up, it is correct that our dataset is so small that the network can easily *memorize* it but the XOR problem is important because it means there are networks that can't memorize this data no matter what.

Having said that however, there are varsities of XOR problems with proper train and test sets. here is one (the plot is slightly different):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 =np.concatenate([np.random.uniform(0, 100, 100), np.random.uniform(-100, 0, 100)])
y1 =np.concatenate([np.random.uniform(-100, 0, 100), np.random.uniform(0, 100, 100)])

x2 =np.concatenate([np.random.uniform(0, 100, 100), np.random.uniform(-100, 0, 100)])
y2 =np.concatenate([np.random.uniform(0, 100, 100), np.random.uniform(-100, 0, 100)])

plt.scatter(x1, y1, c='red')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, c='blue')
plt.show()
```

[image: xor data]

hope that helped ;))

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid it doesn't totally answer the question: how does the model "train" on a dataset that contains(and can only contain) 4 data points? Is some kind of bagging (with or without substitution) taking place? I just don't see it. And as an aside - what generated created the graph in your answer?

Comment: I've added the code (with minor differences from plot).
I'm not sure I fully understand your question. When you present a NN with a sample during its training, the weights are slightly changed so the network generate the correct answer. If you keep presenting the network with that sample -assuming the network is able to learn the problem- it will produce the right answer. It's true that few samples are not usually enough for learning the solution to a complex problem but here we are learning a very simple problem (one that only contains 4 samples). Again, not sure I understood the question.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear - in part, it's because I'm not entirely sure what's bothering me here. I edited to question in an attempt to clarify.

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer, I think this explanation will help you understand the answer better. let me know if I hadn't explained it clearly. cheers.

Comment: I can't be sure why unless I see your code, you'll probably need to post a new question for that. What loss function are you using?